# Handle concurrency in ef 4.1 dbContext api

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, dbcontext

I've just started using new dbContext API with poco classes. Now I have  little problem with concurrency handling. In all of my tables I have RowVersion column (fixed, computed). 
I tried to follow this content:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/03/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-9-optimistic-concurrency-patterns.aspx

so I have something like this:

```
using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
{
    bool saveFailed;

    var unicorn = context.Unicorns.Find(1);
    unicorn.Name = "Franky";

    do
    {
        saveFailed = false;
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            saveFailed = true;

            // Update original values from the database
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
        }

    } while (saveFailed);
}
```

But when I am provoking this, it doesn't work as it should. First of all there is no `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception, but `DbUpdateException`.
Then when I catch DbUpdateException, I am getting another exception on `var entry = ex.Entries.Single();` line:

InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: And what are information in `DbUpdateException`, what is inner exception? What did you done to trigger concurrency exception?

Comment: I have put breakpoint on cotext.SaveChanges(), changed something manually in database and then continued.  The inner exception: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Comment: I have put the inner exception, but there is also message in the DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your not checking for the state it might have been deleted

```
var entry = dbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries.Single();

if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
{
    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
}
else
{
  entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
  objContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, dbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries.Select(e => e.Entity));
}
```